# wordpress backup and restore

Tags: wordpress, backup, restore

We have a wordpress site installed on cPanel in hostgator server.
We want to remove it from our account because it is not updated from along time and we do not need it at this period. But we want to keep a backup in case we need it in the future.

Could you please tell me if it is enough to:
1\Export the DB from phpmyadmin.
2\Compress the files in cPanel and download them to my computer.

Is there any more steps to backup our wordpress?

And when we need to restore it the steps should be:
1\Upload the files to cPanel.
2\Create DB in phpmyadmin and import the DB.

Is there any more steps to restore our wordpress?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That about covers it. The only thing you need to be careful of is if the domain changes, or you plan on re-installing everything to a different directory or subdomain.

If the URL changes in any way, that change needs to be reflected under the wp_options table under the site_url option after importing your database. Updating this value to the new URL will allow you to get back into wp-admin, and all bloginfo calls will accurately reflect the new information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a complete backup of your WordPress website from cPanel then **you need to do 2 things**.

1. You must download all the files from the cPanel file manager.
2. Then you need to download a backup of the Database

Here is a video I have found on YouTube, And the contributor takes a full backup and also shows the way to restore the site from the downloaded backup files.

Plus, He was using ***HostGator hosting***. You will benefit.

**YouTube Video Source:**

Title: How to Backup and Restore WordPress Website from cPanel | Easy Way to Backup WordPress Site

And URL: https://youtu.be/-pvDqRGNF-Q